# ping and DUP! packets, but network seems to work fine

Tags: linux, networking, ping, duplicate

We have recently set up a small cluster of GPU workstations and have recently got them networked together. Although connectivity looks fine for e.g. web browsers and SSH, pinging other addresses results in what looks like a duplicate packet (DUP!) with every ping it does. We have set everything up ourselves, so I wouldn't be surprised if it is an issue with settings... and while it could be a hardware issue, I doubt this somewhat.

Does anybody have any idea what's going on? I've looked this up online and it seems others have had this problem, but I didn't find any clear answers (I could have looked more, I suppose). Suggestions on how to get more information are also appreciated... maybe I should run a traceroute? I am utterly clueless.

Comment: Could you check with Wireshark which packets actually get duplicated? Just ICMP echo replies, or everything?

Comment: @grawity: I think that's a great idea, and will try that out. However, I think I'll wait a bit and see if anybody swoops in with a "just edit line foo in /etc/bar.conf"-esque answer.

Comment: *Receiving* duplicate packets from other machines is not something your `/etc` would handle... While you wait, why not install Wireshark? :)

Comment: Would tcpdump not be sufficient? That comes pre-loaded on the CentOS OS we have installed. In any event, I have been playing around with that, based on your suggestion.

Comment: It would suffice, it's mostly a matter of preference. Both tcpdump and tshark/Wireshark have the same libpcap core functionality.

Comment: OK, so I ran tcpdump while the pinging was going; will sanitize and post output above...

Comment: The exact output is not necessary -- just check whether you are getting duplicates for *all* kinds of packets, or just for ICMP.

Comment: OK... how can I tell what things are duplicates? Sorry for being such a n00b. I'm seeing occasional "bad udp cksum" messages being send from the compute node to the dns server...